# How many solution to an equation where 2 variables are odd and the 2 others are even

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given the equation:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=20$$

Find the number of solutions where:

1. Where $x_i\ne7$ for **all** $i=1,2,3,4$.
2. Where $x_i$ are odd, for $1\leq i\leq 4$
3. **Where two variables are odd and two variables are even**

I solved the first two and got to:

**Please correct me if I am wrong**

1. The number of times where 7 is a variable in the solution = $4*D(3,13)=4*C(15,2)=420$ so the total number of solutions with no restrictions on the variables minus that is the solution so: $D(4,20)=C(23,3)=1771$ and $1771-420=1351$ **is the solution**.
2. So to solve this I know that if I take this equation: $2x_1+2x_2+2x_3+2x_4=16$ every variable is even, and if I add 1 to the variables, we get that all variables are now odd and we got to the solution (20), so to simplify the equation: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=8$ and now we only need to solve the number of solutions to this equation without any restrictions and we get $D(4,8)=C(11,3)=165$

And on the third problem, I don't really know how to approach it, I thought about using something similar like I used on the second problem, but ended up stuck, any hint on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but what does $D(\cdot,\cdot)$ represent?

Comment: I thought it is universal thing, from my course it is defined as $D(n,k)=C(n-1+k,k)=C(n-1+k,n-1)$

Comment: Basically it is the number of ways we can put $k$ items in $n$ places, for example given $x_1+x_2+x_3=10$ we need to put $k=10$ items in $n=3$ places.

Comment: This isn't a universal symbol in combinatorics. However, the [Stars and Bars Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) which underlies that symbol is. The S&B Theorem asserts that $C(n-1+k,k)=C(n-1+k,n-1)=$ the number of ways to put $k$ items in $n$ places.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Thanks didn't know that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approaches for $1$ and $2$ look right to me, assuming you got the combinatorial functions correctly calculated.

For the third stage, notice that since $20$ is even, it cannot be the sum of three even and one odd number or three odd and one even number. So the cases hat you are ruling out are a) all four are odd and b) all four are even. You have:

total number of solutions = number with all odd + number with all even + number with half odd half even

You’ve already solved for the number with all odd, and a similar approach can give you the number with all even. So subtract those two values from the total number of solutions to get the answer. Notice that there is no overlap between the three cases. If there were overlap, you’d have to use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Thanks, About 2. No there is no typo, I changed it to 16 because I wanted to add 1 to all variables to make them odd, and because I add +4 in total, 16+4=20 and I get the same equation

Comment: About the solution you gave me, Yeah I didn't though about it, I'll try to get the number of solutions with all even, It should be a little different than the 2. solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you were doing something slightly different, but what you’re doing is correct.

Comment: Just to be clear that I am correct, to solve the total number of solution for variables that are even, I can solve the equation $(2x_1+1)+(2x_2+1)+(2x_3+1)+(2x_4+1)=24$, (subtracting 1 from each variable gives an even number) so basically solving the total solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$? ($D(4,10)=C(13,3)$)

Comment: @Zik332 Yes, or you can directly say "Assume all the $x_i$ are even, so $x_i=2y_i$ and get $2\sigma y_i=20$ and then divide by $2$. There's no need to expand it into an expression with odd numbers first.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $2\Sigma y_i=2y_1+2y_2+2y_3+2y_4=20$

Comment: Right, my bad, thanks! :)

Comment: The OP's answer to the first question is wrong because the OP did not take into account the possibility that two of the variables could equal $7$.

Comment: @Zik332 N F Taussig is correct. You also need to consider the solutions of $7+7+x_3+x_4=20$ or a permutation of that equation.

Answer (score 1):

> Given the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20$$ find the number of solutions where $x_i \neq 7$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

Your answer is incorrect since you did not take into account the possibility that two of the variables could equal $7$.

As you observed, the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20 \tag{1}$$ 
in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{20 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{23}{3}$$
From these, we must exclude those solutions in which at least one of the variables is equal to $7$.  There are four ways to choose which variable equals $7$.  Removing that variable reduces the problem to solving the equation
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 13 \tag{2}$$
in the nonnegative integers.  As you observed, equation 2 has 
$$\binom{13 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{15}{2}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers.  Therefore, there are 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{15}{2}$$
solutions of equation in which a variable is equal to $7$.

However, we have counted those solutions in which two of the variables are equal to $7$ twice, once for each way we could designate one of the variables as being the one that is equal to $7$.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them back.

There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose which two of the variables equal $7$.  Removing those two variables reduces the problem to solving
$$z_1 + z_2 = 6 \tag{3}$$
in the nonnegative integers.  Equation 3 has 
$$\binom{6 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{7}{1}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of solutions of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers if no variable equals $7$ is 
$$\binom{23}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{15}{2} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{7}{1}$$

> Given the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20$$ find the number of solutions in which each variable is odd.

Your answer 
$$\binom{8 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{11}{3}$$ 
is correct, although I would have renamed the variables to avoid confusion.  If we let $x_i = 2y_i + 1$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$, then each $y_i$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $2y_i + 1$ for $x_i$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
2y_1 + 1 + 2y_2 + 1 + 2y_3 + 1 + 2y_4 + 1 & = 20\\
2y_1 + 2y_2 + 2y_3 + 2y_4 & = 16\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 & = 8 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
so the problem reduces to solving equation 4 in the nonnegative integers.

> Given the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20$$ find the number of solutions in which two of the variables are even and two of the variables are odd.

I like Stella's approach.

Here is an alternative.  Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are even and $x_3$ and $x_4$ are odd. Let $x_1 = 2y_1$, $x_2 = 2y_2$, $x_3 = 2y_3 + 1$, $x_4 = 2y_4 + 1$.  Then $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$ are nonnegative integers satisfying
\begin{align*}
2y_1 + 2y_2 + 2y_3 + 1 + 2y_4 + 1 & = 20\\
2y_1 + 2y_2 + 2y_3 + 2y_4 & = 18\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 & = 9 \tag{5}
\end{align*}
Equation 5 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{9 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{12}{3}$$ 
solutions.

Since we can choose which two of the variables are even in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, the number of admissible solutions is 
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}$$
Since solving equation 1 in even nonnegative integers reduces to solving the problem
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 10 \tag{6}$$
in the nonnegative integers, equation 1 has 
$$\binom{10 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{13}{3}$$
solutions in the even nonnegative integers.  Notice that 
$$\binom{23}{3} - \binom{13}{3} - \binom{11}{3} = \binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}$$
as Stella observed.

Comment: For the first part, Its my bad, I meant that NON of the variables can be 7, I'll edit the question now to make it clear. I'll take the advice on the second part! I like that approach for the third part as well, I'll use it If I can thanks!